# Service/framework for hosting a simple CPAN-like file database?

Tags: google-app-engine, frameworks, content-management-system

Lets say I have a program or language and I want to create a service for users to be able to share files related to my program or language.

For example, if I had a circuit modeling program, I would want users to have a place to share circuit models of common devices. If I had a real time strategy or FPS game, I would want players to have a place to share maps for the game. If I had a programming language, I would want people to have a place to share libraries written in that language like CPAN is for Perl or PyPi is for Python.

Is there a service or framework for putting together such a database simply? If there's not, I was considering putting together a Google App Engine template program for this kind of application. I haven't used Google App Engine, but it's my impression that it's well suited for this kind of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the broadest sense, it sounds like you're looking for a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). In more specific terms, though, no, I'm not aware of anything specifically designed for user-submitted content.

My own site, [NUMA](http://www.nmaps.net/), runs on App Engine and does pretty much exactly what you describe. It's custom-written for the game it's based around, though.

Comment: @John 'fraid not. It wouldn't be terribly useful, though, as it's very specific to the game for which it was written.